# Get the ID of a blank input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having 4 input fields with a common class name. I use this to check if it's blank or not.

```
var blank = $('.fourFields').filter(function(){ 
   return !$.trim($(this).val()).length;
}).length;
if( !blank ){
   //do something
} else {
   //how do I use addClass() to the blank input fields here?
}
```

My question is how do I get the ids of the blank input fields?

Comment: @ItayB–or hugely more efficient: `this.id`.

Comment: @RobG-You're right ;-) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .map() to get an array of inputs ids whose value is blank

```
var ids = $('.fourFields').map(function(){ 
   return $.trim($(this).val()) ? undefined : this.id;
}).get();
```

---

If you want to add a class, then a more appropriate solution will be to use .each()

```
var ids = [];
$('.fourFields').each(function () {
    var blank = $.trim(this.value);
    if (blank) {
        ids.push(this.id);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('required', blank);
});
```

Comment: Looks good. thanks. :) How can I use `addClass()` to each blank input field?

Comment: @Bekki you can do it in the loop itself.... if you don't want the ids array for any other purpose then just remove it....

Comment: Given that the value of an input is always a string and the return value of *trim* is also a string, then comparing the value with *undefined* is relying on type conversion (and `===`, which some prefer will fail). You should be comparing to "" (i.e. empty string) and `==` and `===` will work. Similarly, `if (blank)` is better as `if ($.trim(this.value) == '')`.

Answer (score 0):

the ID would be this.id (note, no $)

Answer (score 0):

As non–jQuery alternative, you can get the id array using:

```
var ids = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'),
  function(el){return /^\s*$/.test(el.value)}
).reduce(function(p,c){p.push(c.id); return p;},[]);
```

and to also do the class part (using jQuery):

```
var ids = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'),
  function(el){return /^\s*$/.test(el.value)}
).reduce(function(p,c){
  $(c).addClass('whatever');
  p.push(c.id); 
  return p;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the id's of the blank input fields you can use the below code:

```
 $(".fourFields").filter(function(){ 
         if($(this).val() === '')
       return  alert($(this).prop('id'));
         });
```

You can refer the fiddle below :
http://jsfiddle.net/varun1989/17wkzgqj/2/